# The Chrono Trigger scenario 1 sentence meaning

Tags: meaning, grammar

I will have been studying English for many years now. I have been playing computer games to study English.

I have walked through the game to the scenario as in the picture below.

[image]

It contains a sentence which I cannot understand.

The sentence is

> Say, looks like you got some replacements for Cyrus!

What does the sentence mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that Frog (or Glenn) has brought new friends instead of Cyrus.

- *say* is a colloquial or informal way to start a conversation (see ["Beginning a question with 'Say' " in the English Language and Usage StackExchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/243030/beginning-a-question-with-say))
- sometimes in informal speech speakers omit pronouns like *it*. So read a dummy-it as the subject of *looks*: "[it] looks like..."
- someone might say "it looks like" to make an observation. For instance, you could say to someone late to work, "It looks like you are late," or, more informally, "Looks like you are late."
- "you got some replacements" - *got* is acting as a verb meaning *obtained* or *found*.
- "some replacements for Cyrus" refers to how Glenn's current companions (Crono, Marle) *replace* (take the place of) Glenn's old companion, *Cyrus*. In this case, *for* denotes who was replaced.

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much. I don't really understand the word some replacements, but now I know. Aren't you also play the game ?